# Scroll Snap Over scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap

When I scroll with scroll snap enabled on my webpage in Chrome; it over scrolls, that is, it doesn't stop scrolling. My mouse wheel is fine, my chrome is up to date. It works as expected in Firefox but on webkit browsers like Chrome and opera, it doesn't.

```css
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5em;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.5);
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}

section {
  height: calc(100vh - 14em);
  width: calc(100% - 14em);
  padding: 7em;
  color: white;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: rgb(96, 175, 21);
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: rgb(21, 139, 175);
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: rgb(175, 21, 129);
}

section h3 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

section p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <h3>A subtitle lives here</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi suscipit, nulla, totam eveniet molestiae odit cupiditate accusamus illum voluptatem quibusdam voluptates vitae! Maiores numquam incidunt recusandae exercitationem at magni atque.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>A subtitle lives here</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi suscipit, nulla, totam eveniet molestiae odit cupiditate accusamus illum voluptatem quibusdam voluptates vitae! Maiores numquam incidunt recusandae exercitationem at magni atque.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>A subtitle lives here</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi suscipit, nulla, totam eveniet molestiae odit cupiditate accusamus illum voluptatem quibusdam voluptates vitae! Maiores numquam incidunt recusandae exercitationem at magni atque.
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Try to add: `html { -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;}` and `body {-ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;  -ms-scroll-chaining: none;}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are facing, I tried on the chrome browser on my macbook as well as on the windows machine, can you elaborate more about the platform you are using

Comment: Basically, the scrolling doesn't stop. It scrolls down till the page ends.

Comment: @HakunaMatata I am using sass so the compiler automatically added that stuff for me. My CSS was actually SCSS in this post but someone edited this and converted this to normal css. `-ms-scroll-chaining: none` doesn't work